# How to reverse dictionary order for certain key:value only?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, reverse

```
for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': ['col-xs-4', 'col-cs-4']}):
  option = item.h3.text.strip()

  description = item.find('div', class_='package-description').text

  price = item.find('span', class_='price-big').text.replace('\n',' ').strip()
  price = price[1:]


  # vat_price = item.find('div', class_='package-price').text.strip()
  # vat_id = vat_price.split('(')[1]
  # vat_id = vat_id.replace(')',' ').split('\n')[0]

  try:
    discount = item.find('p', style='color: red').text.strip()
  except:
    discount = 'No discount'

  results_data = {
    'option title': option,
    'description': description,
    'price': price,
    'discount': discount
  }
  # test = dict(sorted(results_data.items(), key=lambda kv:kv[1], reverse=True))

  # print(results_data)
  # print(test)
  sorted_data = dict(sorted(results_data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=False))
  print(sorted_data)
```

`original print data:

{'option title': 'Basic: 500MB Data - 12 Months', 'description': 'Up to 500MB of data per monthincluding 20 SMS(5p / MB data and 4p / SMS thereafter)', 'price': '5.99', 'discount': 'No discount'}

{'option title': 'Standard: 1GB Data - 12 Months', 'description': 'Up to 1 GB data per monthincluding 35 SMS(5p / MB data and 4p / SMS thereafter)', 'price': '9.99', 'discount': 'No discount'}

{'option title': 'Optimum: 2 GB Data - 12 Months', 'description': '2GB data per monthincluding 40 SMS(5p / minute and 4p / SMS thereafter)', 'price': '15.99', 'discount': 'No discount'}

{'option title': 'Basic: 6GB Data - 1 Year', 'description': 'Up to 6GB of data per yearincluding 240 SMS(5p / MB data and 4p / SMS thereafter)', 'price': '66.00', 'discount': 'Save �5.86 on the monthly price'}

{'option title': 'Standard: 12GB Data - 1 Year', 'description': 'Up to 12GB of data per year including 420 SMS(5p / MB data and 4p / SMS thereafter)', 'price': '108.00', 'discount': 'Save �11.90 on the monthly price'}

{'option title': 'Optimum: 24GB Data - 1 Year', 'description': 'Up to 12GB of data per year including 480 SMS(5p / MB data and 4p / SMS thereafter)', 'price': '174.00', 'discount': 'Save �17.90 on the monthly price'}`

What I want is that last annual price to be first so its sorted by most expensive package first. OR just reverse the order so that the last dictionary is at top and so on.

Comment: This will be more concise and easier for people to answer if you clean up the formatting, cut out the beautiful-soup stuff and just focus on the task of sorting the data.  I think you'll need to convert numbers represented as strings into actual numbers (e.g. `'12.0'` -> `12.0`) so you can do a numeric sort instead of an alphabetical one.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to write your question as a "minimal reproducible example": remove everything that actually isn't related to your question, such as the beautiful-soup webscraping; give a small, simple example of a dictionary, and explain what you want to do with it.

Comment: Your question refers to a "last annual price"; it's unclear what that is in the dicts you have given.

Comment: So you have a list of dicts `data = [{'option title': ...}, ...]`. And you want to sort that list in decreasing order of the `price` field in the dictionaries? Would `from operator import itemgetter; data.sort(key=itemgetter('price', reverse=True)` do what you want?

Comment: I tried reverse=true with the test variable if you see. I dont know if thats the same way as you mentioned but what that was doing was reversing the actual keys and not it from asc -> dec. for e.g. with reverse false price was the first field which was great and it started with 5.99. When I change that to reverse = true, description comes first and it ignores the price asc layout and kind of goes back to default.